# how to use the struct defined in a .c file in another file

Tags: c

my test code is below:

main1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern struct tt ;
int main()
{
    struct tt y;
    y.a=255;
    y.b=0;
    printf("tt->a=%#x   ,tt->b=%#x \n",y.a,y.b);
}
```

main2.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 struct tt
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

makefile:

```
main: main1.o
    gcc -o main main1.o
main1.o:  main2.c main1.c
```

but the compiler reports:

```
cc    -c -o main1.o main1.c
main1.c:2: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
main1.c: In function ‘main’:
main1.c:5: error: storage size of ‘y’ isn’t known
make: *** [main1.o] Error 1
```

how do I write code to in a .c file use the struct defined in another .c file ???

thx for your help!

Comment: struct should be defined in .h file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the `struct` in a header file that both `.c` files include. For example:

```
#ifndef __INCLUDE_GUARD_HERE__
#define __INCLUDE_GUARD_HERE__

struct tt {
  int a;
  int b;
};

#endif
```

Now both `.c` files can `#include` the header file.

Comment: Is there a way to not to have the definition inside the header file? Let's say the design enforces me to define the `struct` inside a .c file? Could I access this struct from another .c file somehow? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520877/forward-declaring-an-extern-struct

Answer (score 2):

the error message is very clear. ( error: storage size of 'y' isn't known)

you declare a variable as the name 'yy'

> struct tt yy;

but you use another variable with the name 'y' (it doesn't even exist in this scope)

> y.a=255;

see? yy != y

Comment: It is my mistake, but it is not the problem.