# Forward-declaring an extern struct

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Before I start:

- *Please note* that **I do not want**
  to change the major design I'm presenting you here.
- Feel free to change the title if you think this one doesn't suit well
- The C++ tag is here because the solution should be equivalent for it as well

---

I have a header `breakpoints.h` which declares:

```
typedef struct BreakpointInfo BreakpointInfo;

/*
 * Iterate all breakpoints known to the Breakpoints service,
 * including breakpoints that are created by other (remote) clients.
 */
typedef void IterateBreakpointsCallBack(BreakpointInfo *, void *);
extern void iterate_breakpoints(IterateBreakpointsCallBack * callback, void * args);
```

and a corresponding `breakpoints.c` that defines:

```
struct BreakpointInfo {
    Context * ctx;
    LINK link_all;

    /*
     * A lot of members ..
     */

    LINK link_hit_count;
};
```

Now I would like to use this functionallity in another file `context.c`:

```
#include <tcf/services/breakpoints.h> // The header file 

extern BreakpointInfo;
//extern struct BreakpointInfo; // Also did not work

void MyIterateBreakpointsCallBack(/* struct */ BreakpointInfo *bpInfo, void *args)
{
    bpInfo->file;
}

void thread_function() 
{
    // ..

    iterate_breakpoints(&MyIterateBreakpointsCallBack, 0);

    // ..
}
```

But Intelli-Sense tells me:

```
BreakpointInfo *bpInfo, Error: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed.
```

So the question is:

- Is that even possible **without** moving the definition of `BreakpointInfo` into the header file?

I don't want to change that since it is a quite complex program and I don't want to break its' design by doing such things.

It may be possible that I am using it the wrong way but why would there ba a `iterate_breakpoints()` function available for me to access if I could not access `BreakpointInfo`?

I hope it is clear what I am asking. Please let me know if you need anything to help me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible since in `MyIterateBreakpointsCallBack` you're trying to access members of the type and this requires a complete type at this point.

I am not familiar with the project you're trying to work with but a quick google search hinted me its the tcf.agent project. If this is true, after a quick look in the breakpoints.h file I noticed that there is a `get_breakpoint_attribute()` that gives you a list of name/value pairs. Maybe that should give you the info you need to implement your `MyIterateBreakpointsCallBack()`.

Comment: You were right. It does not work that way but your hint at `get_breakpoint_attribute()` gave me the push into the right direction! Thank you!

Comment: Please accept my edit for others which may find this question. Thanks

Comment: @StefanR.Falk: It says I need 2K rep points to review suggested edits. I don't think I rejected intentionally nor I see any option to accept edits (sorry still learning the StackOverflow best practices).